# how to send ckeditor5 content to python flask on change in the editor content

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, ckeditor5

I am writing a code to get data as user is typing (or copy paste to the editor ) in ckeditor for my spellchecking project, I need to get the data in editor everytime it changes , so i created a variable editorData which will be holding the changed value. But as I am new to web programming I am not able to send this data to server using python flask, here is how my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 – Classic editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/25.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <div id="editor" method ="POST" ></div>
    <script>
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {
            editorData = editor.getData();
        console.log( 'The data has changed!' )
        } );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Python flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def new_post():
    print('hello')
    if request.method == ' POST':
        data = editorData 
       
        print(data)

    return render_template('test-page.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Please help me how can i send the created javascript variables to flask server every time there is change in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the editor into a POST request so you can send the content to the backend

HTML:

```
...
<form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div id="editor" name="content">Content</div>

<p><input type=submit value="Save">

</form>
...
```

Then fetch it with your api.

Backend:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def new_post():
    if request.method == ' POST':
        data = request.form.get("content") 
       
        print(data)

    return render_template('test-page.html')
```